# android jni return multiple variables

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

How to return multiple variables from a `jni` function, avoiding the overhead of an array mangling?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what kind of data structure you would like to return, that will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I would like to return 2 floats

Comment: So `return new float[]{float1, float2};`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I can come up with three different ways to do it.

**Callback**

Call a Java method from your JNI code that takes multiple parameters, set a variable somewhere in your Java code, that you can retrieve when returning from the method.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_name_JNIReturnExample_returnWithJavaCallback(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jfloat param1, jfloat param2)
{
    // Get the class of the current calling object
    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, javaThis);

    // Get the method id of the instance method: void javaCallback(float, float) in my.package.name.JNIReturnExample
    jmethodID callback = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "javaCallback", "(FF)V");

    // Calls my.package.name.JNIReturnExample#javaCallback(float, float);
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, javaThis, callback, param1, param2);
}
```

---

**Return a new Java object**

Instantiate a Java Object (my.package.name.JNIReturnExample) in JNI, and return it to Java.

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_my_package_name_JNIReturnExample_returnObjectValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jfloat param1, jfloat param2)
{
    // Get the class we wish to return an instance of
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "my/package/name/JNIReturnObject");

    // Get the method id of an empty constructor in clazz
    jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", "()V");

    // Create an instance of clazz
    jobject obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, clazz, constructor);

    // Get Field references
    jfieldID param1Field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "param1", "F");
    jfieldID param2Field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "param2", "F");

    // Set fields for object
    (*env)->SetFloatField(env, obj, param1Field, param1);
    (*env)->SetFloatField(env, obj, param2Field, param2);

    // return object
    return obj;
}
```

---

**Pass a Java object as a parameter, and set its fields**

Create a new instance of a Java Object in your Java code, and pass that object as a parameter to your JNI function.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_name_JNIReturnExample_setObjectFields(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis, jobject obj, jfloat param1, jfloat param2)
{
    // Get the class of the input object
    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

    // Get Field references
    jfieldID param1Field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "param1", "F");
    jfieldID param2Field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "param2", "F");

    // Set fields for object
    (*env)->SetFloatField(env, obj, param1Field, param1);
    (*env)->SetFloatField(env, obj, param2Field, param2);
}
```

---

Please note that whichever method you decide to use, you should cache the various JNI types `jclass, jmethodID, jfieldID`, because JNI lookup operations are slow, and only really need to be performed once.

---

**Caching**

To cache the JNI references in the Callback method, and call them using the method:

```
static jclass myCallbackClass;
static jmethodID myCallbackMethod;

/**
 * Call this method in JNI_OnLoad
 */ 
void CacheCallback()
{
    // Get a reference to the Callback class
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "my/package/name/JNIReturnExample");

    // Store a global reference, since the local one will be freed when returning from the function.
    myCallbackClass = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, clazz);

    // Get a reference to the static callback method
    jmethodID callback = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, myCallbackClass, "jniCallback", "(II)V");

    // jmethodID doesn't need a NewGlobalRef call
    myCallbackMethod = callback;
}

/**
 * Call this method in JNI_OnUnload
 */
void ReleaseCallback()
{
    (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, myCallbackClass);
    myCallbackClass = NULL;

    // jmethodIDs are safe to keep without an explicit global reference, for this reason, we don't need to delete the reference either.
    myCallbackMethod = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hey, with first method (callback) can I cache the callback pointer, let's say as a global jni variable, for further use (after leaving the function)?

Comment: I edited the answer to show a way to cache the callback class and method. The easiest way to cache the method is to use static methods, since you don't need a jobject for those.

Comment: Great answer! I think this is probably the fastest method there is, isn't it?

Comment: I believe so, you could however speed up the "Return a Java Object" method as well by caching the jclass and jmethodID reference. You could then use a constructor with parameters instead of Set<NativeType>Field, which would reduce the operation to two JNI calls.

Comment: Sounds intersting and useful! Thanks!

Comment: Callback approach helped me to get updated values in my kotlin android class from CPP JNI layer.

Comment: I'll give another one: supply one or more `java.util.function.Consumer`s as parameters, and call them with the desired values from the JNI. Saves you from having to gum up your JNI with your own classes.

Comment: And another one: use arrays as in-out parameters.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more way - jobjectArray

Personally, I needed to return to Java a pair of string and int.

String can easily be put into such array using env->NewStringUTF method
but for int a wrapper must be constructed.

native part:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapp_CallingClass_writeCfgFile(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject obj,
    jobjectArray stringArray,
    jstring filepath){
...     
    std::pair<int,string> ret = generate_config(filePath, reqMsgTypes);

    jobjectArray retobjarr = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(2, env->FindClass("java/lang/Object"), NULL);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(retobjarr, 0, NewInteger(env, ret.first));
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(retobjarr, 1, env->NewStringUTF(ret.second.c_str()));

    return retobjarr;
}

jobject NewInteger(JNIEnv* env, int value){
    jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID integerConstructor = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    return env->NewObject(integerClass, integerConstructor, static_cast<jint>(value));
}
```

and on Java side:

```
Object[] resp = writeCfgFile( msgTypes,  filePath");
Integer i = (Integer)resp[0];
String str = (String)resp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *wrapper*. Then return the wrapper. First create a class with some inner variables which are the multiple ones you want to return. Then use this class as the return type.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JNI, please provide an explanation as to how one could return the wrapper.

Comment: Can you give a basic example? I would like to return 2 float variables from a function.. can this be done without array mangaling or class resolving via the env variable (too slow) ?

Comment: This is one of the techniques suggested in the answer the OP has accepted. Nothing wrong with this answer. @NicklasJensen